# chromedp golang: How to create screenshot and pdf from template HTML string instead of URL?

Tags: go, chromedp

Is it possible to generate PDF/screenshots from HTML template instead of `URL` in chrome dp library?

```
func printToPDF(urlstr string, res *[]byte) chromedp.Tasks {
    return chromedp.Tasks{
        chromedp.Navigate(urlstr),
        //page.SetDocumentContent("body", "<h1>Hello world</h1>"), Something like this is this possible?
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            buf, _, err := page.PrintToPDF().WithPrintBackground(false).Do(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            *res = buf
            return nil
        }),
    }
}
```

Link to library: https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp

Comment: I'm not familiar with chromedp, but from what I can see it uses Chrome (in "headless mode" by default) to render pages, so it definitely needs a fully rendered HTML page to work, a template is not enough. You could maybe use Go's HTTP libraries to set up a local web server to render the pages and point chromedp to a "localhost" URL served by this web server?

Comment: Another way could be to navigate to a data URL like `data:text/html;base64,PGRpdj4gSGVsbG8gPC9kaXY+`, but with large documents this can definitely become problematic (if there are limits on URL length). If you already have the file on disk you can also use the `file://` URL schema to visit it directly. Maybe you can also use an ActionFunc and set the page content like [here](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/827)

Comment: @xarantolus I need to parse the template it's not static. The data comes from db. Now it works as extra requests one for image one for pdf so API is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Answer copied from https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/836#issuecomment-850244316:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "github.com/chromedp/cdproto/page"
    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    // construct your html
    html := "<html><body>test</body></html>"
    if err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        chromedp.Navigate("about:blank"),
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            frameTree, err := page.GetFrameTree().Do(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            return page.SetDocumentContent(frameTree.Frame.ID, html).Do(ctx)
        }),
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            buf, _, err := page.PrintToPDF().WithPrintBackground(false).Do(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return ioutil.WriteFile("sample.pdf", buf, 0644)
        }),
    ); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```